# PowerShell Closing FileStream

Tags: powershell, filestream

I am reading in a file, encrypting the contents, and writing the cipher text back out to a file using PowerShell.  When the FileStream object ($inFS) is closed, it creates a file in the pwd (C:\docs) named "0".  I opened the file and it had "32" written to it.

The encrypted contents are being written to a file in a different directory with no problems.  I thought maybe there was something in the buffer still so I tried Flush() and Dispose() but same results.  Why is this?

```
$inFile = 'C:\docs\algorithm_fsa.c'
$inFS = New-Object FileStream($inFile, [FileMode]::Open)

DO
{

  $count = $inFS.Read($data, 0, $blockSizeBytes)
  $offset += $count
  $outStreamEncrypted.Write($data, 0, $count)
  $bytesRead += $blockSizeBytes

}While($count > 0)

$inFS.Close()
```

Comment: `$count > 0` -> `$count -gt 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, the `>` character is used for redirection, to pipe the text from one command into a file, or another stream.

With your line of

```
}While($count > 0)
```

You're instructing PowerShell to write the contents of `$count` to a file titled 0. It does this, in whichever directory you happened to be running the script from.

Change that `>` to `-GT`, which is the PowerShell comparison operator for greater than, and you should get the results you're expecting.

Furthermore, this loop needs to be changed because currently, it would only execute one pass through the file, as `$count > 0` is not an actionable comparison. Once you replace > with `-gt` you should be good to go.

Comment: Why didn't I see that...  I'm such a newb.  Thanks.

Comment: Nah, don't feel bad.  PowerShell's usage of `>` was a huge point of contention amongst IT Pros.  It IS confusing.

Comment: Ah.  Glad to see I'm not the only one that made that mistake.  Thanks again.